# Removing transaction qty data when shopping cart contains a certain product

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a flooring supplier and then not only sell flooring but provide free samples. The issue i'm having is that we have created an event to fire when a sample is present but a transaction is also firing meaning they are getting false data into analytics.

I need a way to stop the transaction sending in the data layer in GTM either when a sample is present in the cart of when the sample event fires.

Comment: I'm working with a flooring supplier and they not only sell flooring but also provide free flooring samples. The issue i'm having is that we have created an event to fire when a sample is present, but a transaction is also firing meaning they are getting false data into analytics.

I need a way to stop the transaction sending in the data layer in GTM either when a sample is present in the cart or when the sample event fires.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [help] and in particular the [ask] pages. Your "question" in its current form really doesn't fit the standard required by this site